# Liferay: How to get relative paths to web contents's documents and media

Tags: jsf, liferay, portlet

Under **Web content** I set my **structure** to have an application field: "**Documents an media**".

Through this field user can add various files which are then displayed in my .xhtml.

User can make this "**Documents and media**" field **repeatable** to add more files.

How could I iterate through **all added files** and get their relative paths.

If my Documents and media field is not repeatable I can get relative path like this:

```
    public String getWebContentTitle(String title, String nodeName) throws PortalException, SystemException {
        FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        ThemeDisplay themeDisplay = (ThemeDisplay) context.getExternalContext().getRequestMap().get(WebKeys.THEME_DISPLAY);
        long groupId = themeDisplay.getScopeGroupId();
        JournalArticle article = JournalArticleLocalServiceUtil.getArticleByUrlTitle(groupId, formatUrlTitle(title));
        String languageKey = context.getExternalContext().getRequestLocale().toString();
        JournalArticleDisplay articleDisplay = JournalContentUtil.getDisplay(groupId, article.getArticleId(), article.getTemplateId(), languageKey, themeDisplay);
        JournalArticle journalArticle = JournalArticleLocalServiceUtil.getArticle(groupId, article.getArticleId());
        String myContent = journalArticle.getContentByLocale(languageKey);

        if (nodeName != null) {
            String nodeText=getParseValue(nodeName, journalArticle, myContent);
            return nodeText;
        } else
        {
            String ret=articleDisplay.getContent(); 
            return ret;
        }
    }

    private String getParseValue(String fieldname, JournalArticle article, String locale) {
        String nodeText = "";
        try {
              Document document = SAXReaderUtil.read(article.getContentByLocale(locale));
              Node node = document.selectSingleNode("/root/dynamic-element[@name='" + fieldname +"']/dynamic-content");
              nodeText = node.getText(); 
        } catch(Exception e){

        }
        return nodeText; 
    }
```

This method return relative path to my added document (say horses.pdf).

How could I get relative paths to more documents added through "Documents and media field", which is repeatable and has defined specific Variable name (say HorsesPdfs?)

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

[image: Documents and media field - repeatable (green plus on picture)]

Comment: If i understand correctly you have more than one JournalArticle and what you want to do, is get all contents of the articles and find the linked files?

Comment: Yes I'll have many Journal Articles. Each of them has a "Documents and media" field. This field is repeatable. How would I iterate through all the added Files through repeatable "Documents and media" field?

Comment: In reality I have many horses. Each has its own site and Journal Article. And on each site of a horse many pdf files could be added.
I can get the web content with the above method which I pass the correct "Node name". My question is how would I get content/paths of repeatable "Documents and media" etries?

Comment: you could use a framework like JerichoHTML to search the JournalArticles content for the requered html tags and extract the content

Comment: What do you do you mean by required HTML tags?

Comment: When you return `String ret=articleDisplay.getContent(); `, what are you doing with it? It seems i dont understand your workflow with the horses :/

Comment: You're right. I didnt include getParseValue method which actually returns the text. (i edited the question) Horses: Web content title is specific - ie.: horse_#{horse.id}. So i can retrieve the correct article because I know the title. And because I also add the node name to the call I can also get the content of specific part of web content such as HorseDescription. I can also get one file per added "Documents and media" field.But I cannot get many PDFs added through "Documents and media" field. I should somehow find it and then iterate through it.I tried with sth like ....

Comment: .... DLFileEntryLocalServiceUtil.getFileEntries(groupId, folderId, -1, -1, null); But I cannot get the folderId of my web document. Do you maybe know how could I get folderId? Maybe this isn't even the right method?

Comment: Facing same issue. did you find any solution ?

Answer (score 1):

You could try

```
DLAppLocalServiceUtil.getFileEntries(REPOSITORY_ID, FOLDER_ID), probably better than DLFileEntry as its the new approach that takes workflows in consideration.
```

Where

```
REPOSITORY_ID = parent group, which is by default LR´s one GroupLocalServiceUtil.getGroup(COMPANY_ID, GroupConstants.GUEST).getGroupId()

COMPANY_ID = PortalUtil.getDefaultCompanyId(); //If just one instance, if not, better to play with CompanyLocalServiceUtil to match your Id
```

For FOLDER ID, you can use root older of LR´s Doc & Media which is

```
FOLDER_ID = DLFolderConstants.DEFAULT_PARENT_FOLDER_ID; //or find it e.g DLAppLocalServiceUtil.getFolder( repositoryId, DLFolderConstants.DEFAULT_PARENT_FOLDER_ID, FOLDER_NAME).getFolderId();  if you programtically used addFolder(long userId, long repositoryId, long parentFolderId, String name, String description, ServiceContext serviceContext)
```